# Proving that $u$ and $v$ are linearly independent, given the independence of $T(u)$ and $T(v)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $T$ is a linear transformation and that $T(u)$ and $T(v)$ are linearly independent. Prove that $u$ and $v$ are linearly independent.

I have no idea where to start in this case. Just need a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: What are $u,v$?  Single vectors?

Comment: Assuming that  $u$ and $v$ are vectors in a vector space $V$ and that $T$ is a linear transformation from $V$ to another vector space $W$.  Let  $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be scalars such that   
$$\alpha u + \beta v=0$$ 
To prove $u$ and $v$ are linearly independent, we must prove that $\alpha=\beta=0$.
Apply $T$ to both sides, use the fact $T$ is linear and then use the fact that  $T(u)$ and $T(v)$ are linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 \in \mathbb{F}$ and assume that $\lambda_1 u + \lambda_2 v = 0_V$. Apply the linear map $T$ to both sides of the equality and use the independence of $T(u)$ and $T(v)$ to deduce that $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = 0$, showing the independence of $u$ and $v$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Because $T(u),T(v)$ are linearly independent, we know that if $c_1,c_2$ are constants such that
$$
c_1 T(u) + c_2T(v) = 0
$$
then we must have $c_1 = c_2 = 0$.  Now, suppose that $c_1,c_2$ are such that 
$$
c_1 u + c_2 v = 0
$$
how can we show that $c_1$ and $c_2$ are necessarily zero?